# How to get entry value from form control value

Tags: angular, forms, form-control

I have a general question.
I have a form with view input fields.
In the input field I can set for example names and then be able to submit the form.

In the second step, I can view this form with already filled input fields and can generate new empty fields.

For the already filled input fields I would like to render a button but only if the field already has an input from previous submit.

I am asking myself whether there is a way to check whether input field has already an input and the input field is hence disabled

Comment: form.get('yourctrl').value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible there are some ways to do it.

```
this.form.value; // It will give you a complete form object.

this.form.get("controlName").value; // it will give yo you the controller value only.

this.form.controls.controlname.value; // it will give yo you the controller value only.
```